# How Do I Configure Ubuntu 21.04 so the Display's Backlight Goes Off when the Display is Locked

Tags: drivers, nvidia, backlight

I am running Ubuntu 21.04 LTS on a MacBookPro (5.3 model).
The display's backlight does not go off when the computer is inactive (Apple Logo is always lit).

Configuration:
I was getting a purple screen while booting, so I configured /etc/default/grub as follows:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="acpi_backlight=video nomodeset"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="noveau.modeset=0"
```

I also installed a current Nvidia driver:

```
sudo apt install Nvidia-driver-470 Nvidia-settings
```

Running OS X El Capitan and/or Catalina, the backlight goes out.
Is it bad if the backlight is always on?

The graphics controller is an Nvidia GeForce 9400M.
Is the nouveau driver in Nvidia-driver-470 the right driver for this GPU?

Comment: Remove `nomodeset`.

Comment: Removed ‘nomodeset’ …  Didn’t help.